# Codeigniter 4 Visual Studio database objects suggestions

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense, autosuggest

I've setup a new Codeigniter 4 project and I would like to use the inbuilt model functions. While I'm using them I noticed my Visual Studio is unable to suggest the correct object attributes in fetched data objects. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Maybe somebody can share his settings for that?

I have a simple UserModel like that below:

```
class UserModel extends Model
{
protected $table      = 'users';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

protected $useAutoIncrement = true;

protected $returnType     = 'object';
protected $useSoftDeletes = true;

protected $allowedFields = ['username', 'status', 'status_message'];

// Dates
protected $useTimestamps = false;
protected $dateFormat    = 'datetime';
protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';

// Validation
protected $validationRules      = [];
protected $validationMessages   = [];
protected $skipValidation       = false;
protected $cleanValidationRules = true;

// Callbacks
protected $allowCallbacks = true;
protected $beforeInsert   = [];
protected $afterInsert    = [];
protected $beforeUpdate   = [];
protected $afterUpdate    = [];
protected $beforeFind     = [];
protected $afterFind      = [];
protected $beforeDelete   = [];
protected $afterDelete    = [];

// Entities and Models
protected $authIdentitiesModel  = null;

protected $user                 = null;
protected $entityClass          = User::class;

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->authIdentitiesModel  = new AuthIdentitiesModel();
    $this->user                 = new User;
}

public function getPasswordHash(int $userID){
    return $this->authIdentitiesModel->find($userID)->secret2;
}

public function resetPassword(string $newPassword){
    return $this->authIdentitiesModel->resetPassword($newPassword);
}
}
```

Now it would be cool, and I know PhPStorm/Intellij is able to do that, and I am sure there is also a way in VisualStudioCode, that VSCode gives me suggestions when I am using the objects:

```
  function test(){
     $users = $this->findAll();
     foreach($users as $user){
         $user->[ HERE SUGGESTIONS TAB with the attributes like (user_id, username, ...) ]
     }
  }
```

I am using PHP IntelliSense extension and PHP Intelephense, but I think I am doing something wrong.I also already setup the entities and included them correctly, but I dont get any suggestions.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: user_id and username don't seem to exist in that class. And all the other properties are protected so they aren't visible outside the class.

Comment: Sure thing, the info should be fetched from the db. findAll() is a inbuilt function which targets to the table-name specified in the file. So I could go over db and check which columns there are OR I go through a entity (which i did) but VSC dont recognize this in a simple function without initialize the entity every time

Comment: So findAll will return an array of `UserModel` objects, is that correct? If so then, my first comment still applies. If a class doesn't have a public property with a certain name, then it isn't accessible outside the class, and therefore you can't expect intellisense to suggest it to you either. And if the code is creating the properties dynamically, then their names can't  be known before runtime. Did you actually try typing the names you want manually and just running the code? Does it work then?